# How can I sync my Windows Phone device with my Mac?

Tags: sync, macos

I'm using OS X Lion on a MacBook Pro. I know I can use iTunes to sync music, apps, contacts, calendars, and such with iOS devices. What are my options for syncing a Windows Phone device?

Comment: please mark this question as answered or tell us what you still need to know. thank you!

Comment: And what does one do if they don't have Mountain Lion? We are still on Snow Leopard, and are still leery of Lion. Now what. Bluetooth doesn't work either.

Comment: SKYDRIVE is about all I figure ... TRYING it now.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just use [Windows Phone 7 Connector for Mac](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/apps/mac-connector.aspx) to sync your Windows Phone data with your Mac machine.

> Windows Phone 7 Connector for Mac is a simple, easy-to-use program for Macs that you can use to:
>
> - Sync music, movies, TV shows, and podcasts from your existing Apple iTunes library to your Windows Phone or Zune HD
> - Sync pictures and videos from your existing Apple iPhoto library to your Windows Phone or Zune HD
> - Retrieve pictures and videos taken on your Windows Phone and automatically import them into your existing iPhoto library
> - Browse and preview media items stored on your Windows Phone or Zune HD
> - Download and install operating system updates for your Windows Phone
>
> Requires a Mac computer running Mac OS X version 10.6.6 or later

Comment: link does not take us to the correct place...

Comment: that link was for the "old" Windows Phone 7... unfortunately I don't know if there's such an app for Windows Phone 8.x or Windows Mobile 10.

Answer (score 3):

To sync contacts and calendars you may use some service like Google Mail/Calendar.

I don't know any "offline" sync option to sync directly.

Mac OS X (since 10.7) provides you the ability to sync your local calendar with Google or Yahoo!.

Another option would be using an Exchange server (your own or a hosted one).

Comment: A few too many "I think"s in this answer.

Comment: You're free to propose edits to my post if it doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: I mean to say that you shouldn't post answers if you aren't sure of something. The answer should be definite and not maybe.

Comment: @row1 - Would you prefer unsure answers that you can try out yourself, or no answer at all? Many responders may not have a good way of testing their own solutions, even when they feel fairly confident about them.

Comment: @Katana314 the original answer read a bit more like a series of guesses rather than a confident answer. It reads fine as it is now. But my second comment was perhaps a bit strict.